# Create Virtual Directories in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtual-directory, iis-7.5

My asp.net web application knows how to create sub-applications (asp.net applications with web.config file, located in sub folders of the root application).

Now, I need to configure each sub-application in the IIS with a Virtual Directory, AND, make this new virtual directory an application in a specified application pool.

Is there any API for IIS7.5 using .NET ?

Comment: there is no such thing as C#.NET.

Comment: Please see the answers to this question to accomplish this in C#.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371725/iis-how-to-create-virtualdirectory-in-website-with-microsoft-web-administration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration(VS.90).aspx) which comes with IIS >= 7.0

There is a similar question here on SO: [creating Virtual directory in IIS 7.0 using c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755316/creating-virtual-directory-in-iis-7-0-using-c-net)
The link provided in the first answer shows how to create virtual directory using the old Metabase API (used in IIS Versions prior to 7.0) and another method that uses appcmd.exe.  appcmd is the command line version of the Microsoft.Web.Administration API.

An example that uses the API directly (IMO the best approach), can be found here:
[How to Use Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/165/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration/)