# IIS: How to create virtualdirectory in website with Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: c#, iis

I'm searching for a way to create virtual directory with Microsoft.Web.Administration in a Default Web Site but without creating application.

The only way I found, creates application:

```
Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager manager = new Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager();
Site defaultSite = manager.Sites[ "Default Web Site];
Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application app =
defaultSite.Applications.Add( "\virtDir", "c:\\path" );
manager.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Please find the link below :

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755316/creating-virtual-directory-in-iis-7-0-using-c-net][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755316/creating-virtual-directory-in-iis-7-0-using-c-net

Answer (score 8):

This might be what you are after:

```
var serverManager = new ServerManager();
serverManager.Sites["WebsiteName"].Applications["ApplicationName"].VirtualDirectories.Add("VirtualDirectoryName, "VirtualDirectoryPath");
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is still relevant but it's fairly hard to find any answers by searching alone. As I'm just struggling with answer to this exact question, the best I came up with is that in order to access virtual directories of a Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site you access the first application on it:

```
var serverManager = new ServerManager();
site = serverManager.Sites.Add(websiteName, physicalPath, port);
var dirs = site.Applications[0].VirtualDirectories;
```

A bit counter-intuitive but it seems like IIS will create a default application for a web site that you add.

Comment: Apparently Application[0] is the default app that the web site runs under. This worked for me to be able to add a Virtual Directory Directly to the root .

Comment: Worked for me, too - nice one.